# How to create a function that will return a friend's id. The friend table has two primary keys and one foreign key id from the user table

Tags: sql

I tried this way:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `num_friends`(id int) RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    declare res int;

    select id 
    into res 
    from friendship 
    where `id_friend` = id or `id_user` = id;

    return (res);
END
```

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: A table can only have one primary key. However, that primary key can have two columns.

Comment: A function that selects table data can never be deterministic.

Comment: The function should count all the friends, and return their id.
If it returns id as far as i understand, the function must be deterministic, or am i wrong?